# Fill in PDF Forms from VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation

I am being tasked with creating a Windows application in VB.Net, and one of the requirements is to read data from an MSSQL database, and put in certain values into a PDF form. How can I achieve putting data into a pre-existing PDF file using VB.Net? Also, is it possible to put the PDF file in as a resource instead of calling it externally?

Comment: You can't write a "native Windows application in VB.Net". Period. You need C/C++ for that.

Comment: @MitchWheat Is there a better place I could ask this then? It's for a volunteer organization, and programming isn't my main job, just a skill I do in my spare time

Comment: This is the right place, it's just a question of semantics. I've removed the "native" reference in your question. For a possible solution, see below. :)

Comment: @kdmurray Thank you for the edit, and the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to take advantage of a 3rd party component like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which is a PDF library. It's written in C#, but could be added to your existing solution as a separate project, or compiled and referenced as a library.

This library specifically references the ability to fill in PDF forms and should fit the bill for filling in your pre-existing PDF form programatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used for filling PDF forms.

There are samples for the library (C# and VB.NET versions available) that show how to:

- [Fill existing form](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FillForm)
- [Find control by name](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FindControlByName)

And you might find [Write data from a database to PDF](https://bitmiracle.com/blog/write-data-from-a-database-to-pdf) blog entry useful in your case, too.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.